# Days left colomn in Backlogs/Queries view

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to add a `Days left` to the `Finish Date` date in the Backlogs/Queries view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The days remaining is only applicable on the Overview (team homepage) and the Sprint view.

The days remaining is a team feature and is not relevant on the Backlog which is a view optimised for the Product Owner and Product Planning. Sprint/Iterations are tactical, Backlogs are strategic.

There is no way, on a query, to know which sprint is of interest. Queries are not team aware and thus cant show team data like sprint dates and time remaining. The Query would not know what team you wanted to see data for...